# Ng-Bind-Html inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, filter, ng-bind-html

I'm making a custom autosuggest component where I hit a web service with a search term and it returns a list of suggestions which I display.

My issue is, I want to bold the matching term inside the list and angular is not playing nice with the extra html. I've seen countless and countless examples using ng-bind-html which I've gotten to work if I can bind to specific values, but not with a dynamic list of values.

This is my first angular project so I'm sure there is something simple I'm missing. The code I'm posting renders the html correctly but it only displays the last result multiple times (I understand why).

How can I accomplish what I'm trying to do?

---

#### Here is my jade code :

```
#search-main(ng-controller="autocomplete" data-api-url="/autocomplete.json")
  input(type="search" placeholder="Search" ng-model="termToComplete")
  input(type="image" name="submit" src="/search-icon.gif", alt="Submit")
  ul.autoSuggest(ng-if="items.length")
    li.fade-in(ng-repeat="item in items")
      h2: a(href="{{item.url}}" ng-bind-html="html")
```

---

#### Here is some of my js

```
app.filter('html', ['$sce', function ($sce) { 
  return function (text) {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
  };    
}])

app.controller('autocomplete', function($scope, $element, $timeout, acAPIservice, $location, $sce){
  $scope.items = [];
  $scope.apiUrl = $element.attr('data-api-url');
  $scope.termToComplete = undefined;

  $scope.showSuggestion = function(){
  var payload = {
    term : $scope.termToComplete
  }

  acAPIservice.getSearch($scope.apiUrl, payload)
    .success(function(data){
      $scope.items = $scope.items.concat(data.results);
      $scope.findMatch();

   })
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config){      
      $scope.items = [];
   });
  }

  //iterates over the results and bolds matching terms
  $scope.findMatch = function(){
    var term = $scope.termToComplete;
    angular.forEach($scope.items, function(value, key){
    $scope.items[key].title = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.items[key].title.replace(new RegExp('(^|)(' + term + ')(|$)','ig'), '$1<b>$2</b>$3'));
    $scope.html = $scope.items[key].title;
      });
   }


  $scope.$watch('termToComplete', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    // reset everything
    $scope.items = [];
    $scope.start = 0;
    $scope.end = 0;
    $scope.total = 0;
    // if we still have a search term go get it
    if($scope.termToComplete){
      $scope.showSuggestion();
    }
  });
});
```

---

#### Here is my test-Json :

```
{
    "start" : 1,
    "end" : 8,
    "total" : 27,
    "results" : [{
        "id" : 0,
        "title" : "here is a title",
        "url" : "google.com"
    }, {
        "id" : 1,
        "title" : "here is another title",
        "url" : "google.com"
    }, {
        "id" : 2,
        "title" : "and another title",
        "url" : "google.com"
    }]
}
```

---

#### NOTE:

`acAPIservice` is just a factory that hits an API and returns the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to define `$scope.html` because you are already assigning the HTML to `title`.

You just need to use it right in your `ng-repeat` loop:

```
li.fade-in(ng-repeat="item in items")
  h2: a(ng-href="{{item.url}}" ng-bind-html="item.title")
```

---

I also recommend using `ng-href` instead of just `href`, because you are using an angular expression for the link ;)

Comment: wow thank you so much, you have no idea how much time I've spent trying to solve this. I tried this solution yesterday and must have not realized it worked... Cheers m8!